# Android studio preview not showing title bar and menu bar?

Tags: android-studio, preview

I'm trying to create an app, but for some reason i can't see the title bar and menu bar in the preview section (shown on picture).

I have tried changing the Theme, still doesn't work.

Looked up other people's issues with it, but no one seems to have it.

[image: On the image you can see what i am talking about]

Answer (score 7):

Doesn't matter, fixed it.

In the preview box click on to the little eye and select "Layout decorations".

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In the preview panel of xml view click the small eye icon and check the "Show System UI". This works for me in Android API-30